# Defining a function that returns "undefined" if its value is outside of a specific range

Tags: function-construction

I want to define a function f(x) which:

- $f(x)=x^3 +10x+ 5$ if $f(x) >0$
- $f(x)=Undefined$ if $f(x) <0$

I have a idea:

```
f = Function[x, ConditionalExpression[x^3 +10x+ 5, x^3 +10x+ 5 > 0]]
```

but if $f(x)$ is a complicated and long expression, then the code is very long. 
Any one have another idea?

Comment: Do you want the returned value to the symbol `Undefined`, the string `"undefined"`, or the standard unevaluated expression?  Also, I think if $f(x)$ is a long expression, the code will probably have to be at least as long.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Kuba's answer:

```
f4[x_] := Block[{val = (x^3 + 10 x - 5)}, val /; val >= 0]
```

`f4` will return unevaluated if the condition is not fulfilled. If it is desirable to get some value returned instead, it is convenient to define it as `Indeterminate` or `Undefined` by adding second definition:

```
f4[_] = Undefined
```

Now for `f[1]` you get `6` and for `f[0]` you get `Undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways:

```
f1[x_?NumericQ] := (x^3 + 10 x - 5) /. n_?Negative -> "undefined"
```

or more safe:

```
f2[x_] :=  With[{val = (x^3 + 10 x - 5)}, If[Negative@val, "undefined", val]]
```

another one for open intervals:

```
f3[x_] := Clip[(x^3 + 10 x - 5), {0, ∞}] /. (0 -> "undefined")
```

Comment: You can use `Clip`s third argument to avoid the replacement and (probably) speed this up somewhat seriously, see e.g. `Clip[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3}, {low, high}]`

Comment: @YvesKlett oh of course, what was I thinking about? :) Thanks.