# Deciding whether the return value of a function is defined based on its input

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, argument-patterns

I have been met with the following problem:

I have defined the following:

```
myFunc[e_Integer];
```

That means, if I call:

```
myFunc[0]
```

The output of the program is going to be simply:

```
myFunc[0]
```

Now, I would like to do the following:

If `e > 0`, do something. If `e <= 0`, output `myFunc[0]`, just like in the previous example. How would I go about doing this?

I was thinking about something like this, but I have no idea what to put in the last argument of the If function.

```
myFunc[e_Integer] := If[e>0, e*e , (* ? *) ];
```

Any responses would be greatly welcome.

Comment: p.s. also related: [45351](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45351/5478)

Answer (score 0):

When you type `e_` or `e_Integer` you are using a pattern.  You can put [constraints](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) on the pattern as well using the `;/` operator

```
myFunc[e_Integer /; e > 0] := e*e
myFunc[0]
myFunc[17]
(* myFunc[0] *)
(* 289 *)
```

Comment: For your definition `myFunc[-1]` doesn't return `myFunc[0]`, but maybe I'm misreading the question.

Comment: I read the question that he wanted it to return `e^2` if it were positive, but to behave the same way as before if it were negative.  He did write it ambiguously.

Comment: @Guest245 Please clarify if you really mean "If `e <= 0`, output `myFunc[0]`" or if you mean "If `e <= 0`, output `myFunc[e]`".

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways to get it working using `If` in the definition of the function.

1) Using [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html)

```
myFunc[e_Integer] := If[e > 0, e*e, Defer @ myFunc[0]]
```

2) Using [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html)

```
myFunc[e_Integer] := If[e > 0, e*e, HoldForm @ myFunc[0]]
```

3) Using [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html)

```
myFunc[e_Integer] := If[e > 0, e*e, Inactivate @ myFunc[0]]
```